# Non-negligible execution plan difference with Oracle when using jdbc Timestamp or Date

Tags: oracle, jdbc, timestamp, sql-execution-plan

I'm analysing Oracle execution plans and found an astonishing fact. Check out this query. The hint is just to display that I have an index and I'd expect Oracle to use it for range scans:

```java
// execute_at is of type DATE.
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT /*+ index(my_table my_index) */ * " + 
    "FROM my_table " +
    "WHERE execute_at > ? AND execute_at < ?");
```

These two bindings result in entirely different behaviour (to exclude bind variable peeking issues, I actually enforced two hard-parses):

```java
// 1. with timestamps
stmt.setTimestamp(1, start);
stmt.setTimestamp(2, end);

// 2. with dates
stmt.setDate(1, start);
stmt.setDate(2, end);
```

1) With timestamps, I get an `INDEX FULL SCAN` and thus a filter predicate

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name                  |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                       |
|*  1 |  FILTER                      |                       |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| my_table              |
|*  3 |    INDEX FULL SCAN           | my_index              |
--------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   1 - filter(:1<:2)"
   3 - filter((INTERNAL_FUNCTION(""EXECUTE_AT"")>:1 AND 
               INTERNAL_FUNCTION(""EXECUTE_AT"")<:2))
```

2) With dates, I get the much better `INDEX RANGE SCAN` and an access predicate

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name                  |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                       |
|*  1 |  FILTER                      |                       |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| my_table              |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | my_index              |
--------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   1 - filter(:1<:2)"
   3 - access(""EXECUTE_AT"">:1 AND ""EXECUTE_AT""<:2)
```

Now my example is just an example. The real query is much more complex, where it is essential to have `RANGE SCANS` or `UNIQUE SCANS` (depending on the predicate) rather than `FULL SCANS`.

Is there something I'm misunderstanding here? Can someone point me to the best solution/practice? Because in the Java world, I think that `java.sql.Timestamp` is much more suitable but most of our columns are of Oracle's `DATE` type. We're using Java 6 and Oracle 11g

Comment: Note, I found a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945603/why-is-oracle-so-slow-when-i-pass-a-java-sql-timestamp-for-a-date-column/6620643

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So the thing is, Oracle timestamps and Oracle dates are two different datatypes.  In order to compare a timestamp to a date Oracle has to run a conversion - that INTERNAL_FUNCTION().  The interesting design decision is that Oracle converts the table column rather than the passed value, which means the query no longer uses the index.

I have been able to reproduce your scenario in SQL*Plus, so it's not a problem with using `java.sql.Timestamp`.  Casting the passed timestamps to dates does resolve the problem...

```
SQL> explain plan for
  2      select * from test1
  3      where d1 > cast(to_timestamp('01-MAY-2011 00:00:00.000', 'DD-MON-YYYY Hh24:MI:SS.FF') as date)
  4       and d2 > cast(to_timestamp('01-JUN-2011 23:59:59.999', 'DD-MON-YYYY Hh24:MI:SS.FF') as date)
  5  /

Explained.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display)
  2  /

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1531258174

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |       |    25 |   500 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TEST1 |    25 |   500 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | T1_I  |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
   2 - access("D1">CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP('01-MAY-2011 00:00:00.000','DD-MON-YYYY
              Hh24:MI:SS.FF') AS date) AND "D2">CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP('01-JUN-2011
              23:59:59.999','DD-MON-YYYY Hh24:MI:SS.FF') AS date) AND "D1" IS NOT NULL)
       filter("D2">CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP('01-JUN-2011 23:59:59.999','DD-MON-YYYY
              Hh24:MI:SS.FF') AS date))

18 rows selected.

SQL>
```

But I don't think that helps you any: it would be easier to just pass dates instead.

---

Interestingly, building a function-based index casting the date columns to timestamps doesn't help.  The `INTERNAL_FUNCTION()` call isn't recognised as a `CAST()` and the index is ignored.  Trying to build an index using `INTERNAL_FUNCTION()` hurls an ORA-00904.

Comment: Casting would be possible, because we use a database abstraction layer for all queries, similar to http://www.jooq.org. But I'm afraid that casting might introduce new problems with functional-based indexes. See this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340738/oracle-execution-plans-when-using-the-like-operator-with-a-deterministic-function. So yes, probably, considering that we only have `DATE` columns in the DB, probably we should transform dates"last-minute" from `java.sql.Timestamp` to `java.sql.Date` before binding in the database abstraction layer...

Comment: Using `java.sql.Timestamp` in Java, but binding `java.sql.Date` does the trick. The execution plans are now showing index usage... Let's hope this didn't break other stuff... :)

Comment: Unfortunately, in some cases, Oracle (JDBC, probably) truncates the time part of the `java.sql.Date`. Especially with `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements, this can be quite wrong... :-/

Comment: I guess, casting is the safest here. But I'll check more thoroughly before applying that patch to our database-abstraction...

Answer (score 2):

While [APC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6614440/521799) already sufficiently explains why this is happening, the following blog posts are interesting in case you're trying to solve this problem with JPA and Hibernate:

- http://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/29/leaky-abstractions-or-how-to-bind-oracle-date-correctly-with-hibernate/

Or with JDBC or jOOQ:

- http://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/22/are-you-binding-your-oracle-dates-correctly-i-bet-you-arent/

In particular, a possible solution is to simply pass `oracle.sql.DATE` instead of any `java.sql` type to the `PreparedStatement`