# Java Date as Parameter for Oracle SELECT query in MyBatis

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis, oracle12c, date

I have SELECT queries where a parameter is a Java Date. There is no error in the console but they do not get data from the database.

First query:

```
<select id="getByDate" parameterType="java.util.Date" resultType="domain.Book">
SELECT * FROM BOOK WHERE DTCREATED = #{dateCreated}
</select>
```

I tried also **_date** for **parameterType**, the same happened.
My other queries use **map** for **parameterType** since number of parameters are either 2 or 3.

Again, there is no error. Just no data being returned. For non-Date parameter, queries are working.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It might be that you face the issue with precision of date vs timestamp https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612679/non-negligible-execution-plan-difference-with-oracle-when-using-jdbc-timestamp-o. See https://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/22/are-you-binding-your-oracle-dates-correctly-i-bet-you-arent/ for more details

Comment: java.util.Date s are really just instants in milliseconds.  Might work if you switch the type to java.sql.Date

Comment: @brt I switched the type to java.sql.Date: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date

Comment: @JulezJupiter You'll need to switch the parameterType as well as the field in your java class.  Just for testing, you could switch your WHERE clause to `DTCREATED > #{dateCreated}` or `DTCREATED < #{dateCreated}` just to see if you get any rows.

Comment: @Julez hi, are you able to solve your issue? i having it now. I still unable to solve it, altho if i put  ">" it is able to come out, but i want it to be "=".