# Java Date as Parameter for Oracle SELECT query in MyBatis [not get answered]

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis, date, oracle18c

I have a similar questions with post

[Java Date as Parameter for Oracle SELECT query in MyBatis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53089233/java-date-as-parameter-for-oracle-select-query-in-mybatis)

but that question didn't get answered and i did post there and haven't heard from it. Mine is quite similar, if i remove the date filter it works perfectly.

myBatis version mybatis-spring-boot-starter v1.3.2  [consider it cant be upgrade]

**my mapper xml as below**

```
<mapper namespace="com.wind2.schedulerworker.dw.mapper.ProductBetlineReportMapper">
    <resultMap id="productBetlineReportMap" type="ProductBetlineReport">
        <id column="REPORT_DRAW_DATE" property="reportDrawDate" jdbcType="DATE" />
        <id column="DRAW_DATE" property="drawDate" javaType="java.util.Date" jdbcType="DATE" />
        <id column="PBID" property="pbid" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
        <result column="PRODUCT_CHANNEL" property="productChannel" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
    </resultMap>

<select id="selectProductBetlineReportCreated" resultMap="productBetlineReportMap" parameterType="java.util.List">
    <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="productBetlineList" separator="union all">
        SELECT REPORT_DRAW_DATE, PBID, DRAW_DATE FROM PRODUCT_BET_LINE_REPORT_CREATED
        WHERE PBID = #{item.pbid} AND DRAW_DATE = #{item.drawDate}
    </foreach>
</select>

</mapper>
```

**my java class as below, i use java.util.Date**

```
import java.util.Date;

public class ProductBetline {
    ....
    private Date drawDate;
    ....
}
```

i did quite a few troubleshoot and searched from internet, i did get return result if i change my xml condition to **#{item.drawDate} > DRAW_DATE** but what i want is "=". i not sure maybe its also timestamp problem or what, but when i select back the input date i put its the same as the db one. for example, *24-JUL-19 00:00:00*(from oracle db) and *2019-07-24 00:00:00*(from java input). I not sure is the revert of the of the year and date cause problem or what (treat date as year or year as date), but it seems not like it, because if it would my statement would not be correct.

Appreaciate anyone can help me. I troubleshoot this for hours now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it (i.e. `=` worked as expected). Could you provide a small demo project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) ? It should include minimum set of DDL/DML for reproduction.

Comment: If you're sure the problem is with DRAW_DATE condition, you can try to look [here](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html), section Parameters, and try to specify the explicit java and db type of your filter (something like #{item.drawDate,jdbcType=DATE}), be sure the column doesn't use timestamp.