# JPA 2 - How to cache/optimize count queries?

Tags: query-optimization, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, java-ee-6

I have Java EE application, where I have list of groups. I want to display number of items in every group, so I do:

```
SELECT COUNT(p) FROM Product p WHERE LOWER(p.group) = LOWER(:group)
```

Group is plain String.

Problem is when I have 50+ groups, time to load page is about 10s, which is unacceptable. When I remove counting time drops to ~1s. How can I optimize/cache this?

My first idea was to use EJB singleton to keep counts locally and refresh them with EJB timer.

I'm using glassfish v3, eclipselink and oracle 10g database on same machine.
I'm using cache in eclipselink, but it seems not to cache count queries.

```
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
<property name="eclipselink.cache.size.default" value="500"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about selecting all groups and associated counts in one query? This is not a JPA answer, but a plain SQL one:

```
SELECT LOWER(p.group), COUNT(*) 
FROM Product p
GROUP BY LOWER(p.group)
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. Next I'm spliting results in java like this http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/jpa-query-to-return-a-map/1457#1457. I'm also using Eclipselink Query Results Cache http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_Advanced_Query_API_(ELUG)#Using_Queries_and_the_Cache and now time to render 131 groups with counts is 1-2 sec.

Comment: @mm1: 1-2 seconds is still slow if you ask me. Maybe you should consider making your data all lower-case (avoiding the `LOWER` function), or maybe adding a function-based index, as suggested by JB Nizet

Comment: Actually is more like 1sec than 2. And it's not only loading group counts but list of products with some images. I'm not using LOWER in this query. Index is not posiible since I'm using database view.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing in `:group` as parameter anyway, I would delegate the lowering part into java code.

```
SELECT COUNT(p) FROM Product p WHERE LOWER(p.group) = (:groupInLower)
```

This might have been optimized out by the SQL interpreter anyway, but it's worth a try...

Comment: While being counter-intuitive, this might indeed solve some problems. I have recently had a similar issue with a deterministic UDF in Oracle. See [this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340738/oracle-execution-plans-when-using-the-like-operator-with-a-deterministic-function)

Answer (score 0):

A long query is usually the sign of a missing index in the database. Try adding an index on `product(lower(group))`.

Also, it's hard to say withount knowing the excact use-case, but I find it strange to get the number of products of a group using a group label in the product table. Shouldn't you have a Group entity, and reference the group's primary key in the product table? This would eliminate the need of an index on `lower(group)` (but would need an index on `product.group_id`).